# R - foreach loops with verbose=TRUE

Tags: r, foreach

I am using the `doSMP` R-package along with `foreach loops`.

I have specified `verbose=TRUE` as an optional argument of `foreach` which is reported to be very useful for trouble shooting. I guess this is true: it is very useful... if we understand what it means.

Can you please explain me the following message which is returned after an iteration.

```
got chunk of 1 result(s) starting at # 1
numValues: 2, numResults: 1, stopped: TRUE
returning status FALSE
```

**EDIT**

Following Xu Wang's requirement, here is a minimum working example.

```
library(doSMP)

w <- startWorkers(2)
registerDoSMP(w)

root <- foreach(i=1:2, .verbose=TRUE) %dopar%
{
  sqrt(i)
}

stopWorkers(w)
```

Comment: Better to contact the foreach package developer directly.  Certainly the package documentation is not very forthcoming.

Comment: could you please post your code and data? OR just a minimum working example?

Comment: @Marco, did you hear back on this?  If so can you post the answer?

Comment: @Solomon: I think doSMP is no longer on use. I use doMC instead.

Comment: This `.verbose=TRUE`-option output message ("numValues..., numResults..., stopped...) is from `foreach`, which is still current, and provides the parallel looping for all kinds of back-ends. We still need to know what, e.g. "stopped=TRUE" means.

Answer (score 7):

The message after each iteration is produced by the 'foreach' package. I analyzed package code (mostly the file "foreach.R") and made a slightly modified demonstration in which I use %do% instead of %dopar%. Read the description of the output after the log.

--- log start ---

```
foreach(i=1:2, .verbose=TRUE) %do% { sqrt(i) }
evaluation # 1:
$i
[1] 1

result of evaluating expression:
[1] 1
got results for task 1
numValues: 1, numResults: 1, stopped: FALSE
returning status FALSE
evaluation # 2:
$i
[1] 2

result of evaluating expression:
[1] 1.414214
got results for task 2
numValues: 2, numResults: 2, stopped: FALSE
returning status FALSE
numValues: 2, numResults: 2, stopped: TRUE
calling combine function
evaluating call object to combine results:
  fun(accum, result.1, result.2)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1.414214
```

--- log end ---

**"numValues"** is the number of tasks launched.
**"numResults"** is the number of results received.
**"stopped: FALSE"** (or **"TRUE"**) simply means whether foreach has completed all the iterations.
**"returning status FALSE"** (or **"TRUE"**) displays the output from an internal (to 'foreach' package) function "complete()", which checks whether all work has been done. Depending on the backend, the message "returning status TRUE" may be displayed or skipped (doParallel backend did not and doRedis backend did print the 'TRUE' message in my particular situations).